# What is the correct syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I want to define a block similar to NSArray enumerateObjects:usingBlock

my block is as follows

```
typedef void (^MyBlock)(BOOL *);
```

and i want to invoke it in some method, so that the method would give me the BOOL value to stop

how do I continue from here ?

EDIT:

I want to do the following

```
BOOL replaceSomething;
```

`[self someMethod:MyBlock(&replaceSomething)]` <== this syntax is not correct

```
if(replaceSomething){
do something
}



-(void)someMethod:^void(BOOL *stop){
*stop = YES;
}
```

Comment: your `MyBlock` expect _two (2)_ parameters, not only _one (1)_; 1st parameter an `id`; 2nd parameter a pointer to a `BOOL`. when you called your block you pass only _one (1)_ parameter, the 2nd one only – that is indeed incorrect syntactically. (beside I have no idea what you are really questioning here...)

Comment: I want to invoke some method , it is not my method, it is a delegate method , because stuff are happening out of my control, i want the given method to tell me whether or not to do something according to the setting of the given parameter. the invoked method shows an alertview, and i'm asking the user to tell me something

Comment: I guess you have to provide much more details about the current environment because what you request is highly ambiguous; I could think on a scenario which you cannot do, and I could think on another scenario which may be done. so, please, present correct description about the environment (=class hierarchy and dependency) your are dealing with.

Comment: the question is: what is the `–someMethod:` method's implementation? can you please add it to your post?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a handy and an easy to remember site when dealing with blocks:
http://fuckingblocksyntax.com

What you're looking for exactly is the last part (using typedef):

```
typedef void (^ MyBlock)(id, BOOL);
MyBlock myBlock = ^(id myId, BOOL myBool) {...};
```

P.S. Note that BOOL is not an object, but a primitive type.

Comment: but he wants to use a parameter of pointer to a `BOOL` (= `BOOL *`), because he wants to change that value it inside the block, so the original block definition is correct.

Comment: It certainly does not look that way, even with the edit.

Comment: the post's first sentence is _"I want to define a block similar to NSArray `–enumerateObjects:usingBlock:`"_. I guess that is quite straightforward.